# jquery: addclass to the next element after footer tag

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to the div that follows the footer tag.  I am using .next and addClass in jquery, but is just not working. How would I accomplish this correctly?

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/o6z64f75/7/)

```
<footer class="footer1">
<div class ="d1">
just some test
</div>
</footer>

.d2{
  color:orange;
}
.d3{
  color: green;
}
$('footer').next('div').addClass("d3");
```

Comment: `div` is inside `footer`, not next to it (or after it).

Comment: Next() in this case isn't doing what you think: https://jsfiddle.net/o6z64f75/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your div is not next to footer, it's its child

use this instead:

```
$('footer > div').addClass("d3");
```

the above code will add class to ***ALL*** divs that are ***direct children*** of footer

to select just the first one, use:

```
$('footer > div').first().addClass("d3");
```

Comment: wow, i have used everything, but '>' and thanks for the note on "first" because that is what I needed as well.THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: you can also use *space* `$('footer div')`but it'll select nested divs at all depths.

Answer (score 0):

To look for the div you're after, you could also `.find()` it. Check out the fiddle.

```
$('footer').find('div').addClass("d3");
```

or

```
$('footer').find('.d1').addClass("d3");
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6z64f75/14/

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

your div is first child of footer. So you can use

```
$('footer>div').first().addClass("d3");
```

or

```
$('.footer1>div').first().addClass("d3");
```